# Booting awkwardly placed Windows partition

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, window

I got a SSD which has a linux `/` partition,and another SSD wich has `/boot` partition (of the same linux system) and GRUB. This second SSD boots the system.

Now, I cloned (clonezilla) a windows system from another disk onto the first SSD. That SSD has now:

- grub
- the /boot partition for linux
- Windows' `system reserved` partition
- Windows' main partition (`C:`)

Then I did an `update-grub` (it is an Ubuntu 18.04) expecting that grub would have found the windows system making it bootable, but grub found nothing.

How can I make the cloned windows system bootable?

Comment: Are you using BIOS or UEFI boot for Linux? What did the Windows system use?

Comment: Thanks. I'm using BIOS for both linux and windows. More specifically, windows was cloned from a BIOS disk to another BIOS disk.

Comment: What does os-prober say?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. It works, but just shows the prompt after a couple of seconds..